# Selecting NEXTVAL from H2 Database and DB2

Tags: db2, h2

Currently I am using H2 for integration test and DB2 for DEV and UAT.

To get the next value from a sequence, we are using `Values NEXTVAL FOR SCHEMANAME.SEQNAME` SQL for Db2 and which is working as expected.

However the above SQL not working in the H2 Database and we are using `Select NEXTVAL ('SCHEMANAME','SEQNAME')` in H2. This is not working in Db2

However I need to use same SQL query or both DB2 and H2 to get `NEXTVAL`.

Can we use one SQL to get `NEXTVAL` in both H2 and DB2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL Standard has a `NEXT VALUE FOR sequenceGeneratorName` expression. This expression is supported by both databases:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_12.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_sequencereference.html

https://h2database.com/html/grammar.html#sequence_value_expression

You can test it with

```sql
VALUES NEXT VALUE FOR SCHEMANAME.SEQNAME;
```

Note that you need a recent version of H2 (1.4.199, for example), because old versions of H2 don't support table value constructor (`VALUES …`).

Comment: Thank You. It works fine in both H2 and DB2 and retrieved NEXTVAL